# codigo no guarda imagen en maquina de aws

Tags: php, mysql, aws

estoy haciendo un formulario y uno de los campos a llenar es el de subir una imagen, al enviar el formulario se deberia ver en otra pestaña la imagen subida con el resto de datos, funciona bien de manera local el codigo y en 000webhost tambien pero al hacerlo en la maquina de aws no, alguien sabe que esta mal o me falta instalar algo en la maquina??

codigo donde se registra la imagen:

```
if(!empty($_FILES["imagen"])){
            $imagen = basename($_FILES["imagen"]["name"]);
            $imagen_final = date("d-m-y")."-".date("h-i-s")."-". $imagen;
            $ruta = "img/".$imagen_final;
            
            $uploaddir = "img/";
            if(!is_dir($uploaddir)){
                mkdir($uploaddir, 0777,true);
            }
            $subirarchivo = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"], $ruta);
            $consulta = "INSERT INTO formulario(nombreContacto, cargoEmpresa, nombreEmpresa, direccion, telefono, email, producto, cantidad, comentarios, fecha_reg, imagen) VALUES ('$nombreContacto', '$cargoEmpresa', '$nombreEmpresa', '$direccion', '$telefono', '$email', '$Producto2[0]', $cantidad, '$comentarios', '$fechareg', '$ruta')";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($conex, $consulta);
        }
        else{
            $consulta = "INSERT INTO formulario(nombreContacto, cargoEmpresa, nombreEmpresa, direccion, telefono, email, producto, cantidad, comentarios, fecha_reg) VALUES ('$nombreContacto', '$cargoEmpresa', '$nombreEmpresa', '$direccion', '$telefono', '$email', '$Producto2[0]', $cantidad, '$comentarios', '$fechareg')";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($conex, $consulta);
        }
```

Y este es el codigo donde se muestran la imagen:

```
<b>Imagen: <img src="<?php $result=mysqli_query($conex, "SELECT imagen from formulario where formulario.id=$id");
                                    $result2=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                                    echo $result2[0];
                                    ?>" width="160px" height="160px"></b>
```

Comment: revisa los permisos de acceso a la carpeta

Comment: se me había pasado por completo eso, muchas gracias